# What is the difference between the different colored dots?

Tags: psp, a-space-shooter

When you kill enemies, they can drop green, purple and blue dots. I know that the blue ones give money and always assumed the green ones heal you. But it does not seem to be the case.

So what is the difference between the different colored dots and how many are there besides green, purple and blue?

Comment: Thanks for the edit, but you should rather make it `space-shooter-for-2-bucks` than `a-space-shooter`.

Comment: The Android version is called "A Space Shooter For Free" - As such, we can safely assume "A Space Shooter" as the name for our purposes.

Comment: @user98085 Are the Android and PSP versions different in any way other than price?